# using dropzone.js with pica (or other image compression/resize libraries)

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'd like to resize images before file upload using dropzone.js.  I've tried dropzone's built-in resizing feature, but it does not generate high quality images so I do not find it useful.  I was hoping to use pica (https://github.com/nodeca/image-blob-reduce) to process the files before they are sent to the server by dropzone.js.

I have a simple proof of concept that works so far based on code I've cobbled together from other places.

There are 2 issues...

1. the progress bar doesn't work when uploading the image and the "complete" checkmark that ususally shows up on top of the image doesn't appear either when the upload is finished.  I'm guessing this is because I haven't copied over the values for the following into the new file

   > previewElement: div.dz-preview.dz-image-preview
   >
   > previewTemplate: div.dz-preview.dz-image-preview
2. i cannot add a 2nd/3rd file.  i get the error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'toBlob' of undefined at reducer._create_blob

Here is my semi-working code snippet...

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.2/dropzone.min.css" integrity="sha512-3g+prZHHfmnvE1HBLwUnVuunaPOob7dpksI7/v6UnF/rnKGwHf/GdEq9K7iEN7qTtW+S0iivTcGpeTBqqB04wA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.2/basic.css" integrity="sha512-Ucip2staDcls3OuwEeh5s9rRVYBsCA4HRr18+qd0Iz3nYpnfUeCIMh/82aHKeYgdaXGebmi9vcREw7YePXsutQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
 
   <!-- dropzone.js -->
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.2/min/dropzone.min.js" integrity="sha512-9WciDs0XP20sojTJ9E7mChDXy6pcO0qHpwbEJID1YVavz2H6QBz5eLoDD8lseZOb2yGT8xDNIV7HIe1ZbuiDWg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <script src="js_libraries/pica/image-blob-reduce.js"></script>
    

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone", {
        url: "api/api_uploadPhotos.php",
        autoProcessQueue: false, // use: myDropzone.processQueue() to process
        addRemoveLinks: true,

        parallelUploads: 20,
        maxFiles: 20,

    });

    myDropzone.on("addedfile", function (origFile) {

        currFileType = origFile.type;
        currFileName = origFile.name;
        console.log('currFileType:' + currFileType);
        console.log('currFileName:' + currFileName);

        // get dimensions of image
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(origFile);
        var img = new Image;
        img.onload = function () {

            currFileWidth = img.width; // alert(img.width);
            currFileHeight = img.height;
            console.log('width: ' + currFileWidth);
            console.log('height: ' + currFileHeight);
            URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);

            if (currFileType == 'image/jpeg') {

                // ANCHOR: blob reducer
                reducer._create_blob = function (env) {
                    return this.pica.toBlob(env.out_canvas, 'image/jpeg', 1.0)
                        .then(function (blob) {
                            env.out_blob = blob;
                            return env;
                        });
                };

                // reducer
                reducer
                    .toBlob(
                        origFile, 
                        {
                            max: 1024,
                        }
                    )
                    .then(function (blob) {
                        console.log('done reducer');

                        document.getElementById('result').src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                         var newfile = new File([blob], "file_name.jpeg", { type: "image/jpeg", lastModified: Date.now() });
                        newfile['accepted'] = true;
                        newfile['status'] = 'queued';
                        newfile['upload'] = origFile['upload'];

                        var origFileIndex = myDropzone.files.indexOf(origFile);
                        myDropzone.files[origFileIndex] = newfile;

                    }); // reducer .then
            } // image/jpeg

        };
        img.src = url;

    });
```

the part where the error gets thrown is:

```
return this.pica.toBlob(env.out_canvas, 'image/jpeg', 1.0)
```

I'm not 100% set on using pica, but it produces good images, small file sizes, and is quick.  Fineuploader has integration with pica, but development/support for it was dropped 3 years ago.

Any thoughts are much appreciated.  Thanks!

**EDIT:**
looks like the following code is what was preventing the second image from being added.  commenting out this code, allowed the 2nd/3rd image to get added.  the code was taken from image-blob-reduce's github page, not 100% sure why i copied it during this test.

```
            /*
            reducer._create_blob = function (env) {
                return this.pica.toBlob(env.out_canvas, 'image/jpeg', 1.0)
                    .then(function (blob) {
                        env.out_blob = blob;
                        return env;
                    });
            };
            */
```

**EDIT 2:**
I was right, copying over the

```
  newfile['previewElement'] = origFile['previewElement'];
  newfile['previewTemplate'] = origFile['previewTemplate'];
```

fixed the issue about the upload status and completion UI updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See causes/fixes in the edits in the original question.  If necessary, you can move the reducer._create_blob into the more global space of the file (for instance right after reducer is declared).  that part of the code should not have been in the dropzone event handler.  i actually removed that code ntirely because it forces all output to be jpg.  i want png to stay png after resize/etc.

Comment: Could you share a fully working example? I have a similar need and this is above my expertise.

Comment: This solved the same problem I had with a vue.js project. Was getting the following error on the second attempt to upload a file: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pica') at reducer._create_blob second time await reducer.toBlob". Removing
mounted() { reducer._create_blob = function (env) {
                return this.pica.toBlob(env.out_canvas, 'image/jpeg', 1.0)
                    .then(function (blob) {
                        env.out_blob = blob;
                        return env;
                    });
            };
}
Fixed this